# Eccentricity of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

How is $\frac{PF}{PD} = e = \frac{C}{A}$ ? where e is eccentricity, P stands for any point on the ellipse. $F$ stands for one of the foci. $e$ stands for eccentricity. $D$ is a point on the directrix of the ellipse. 'C' is the distance from the center to the focus of the ellipse 'A' is the distance from the center to a vertex.

This is referring to an ellipse/hyperbola/parabola and their conic sections. The problem is not the proof for how $PF/PD = e$, or how $C/A = e$, but how the two equate to each other. (The letters stem from the points/foci of an ellipse of a cone and its directrix).

What is the answer that does NOT use analytic geometry? (only trigonometry)

Comment: Please provide enough context for us to understand what on earth you are talking about.

Comment: To me it's impossible to undertand your question. Could you explain what PF, PD, C, A, etc. mean?

Comment: It sounds like a conic section problem ... ?

Comment: This is referring to an ellipse/hyperbola/parabola and their conic sections.

The problem is not the proof for how PF/PD = e, or how C/A = e, but how the two equate to each other.

(the letters stem from the points/foci of an ellipse of a cone and its directrix).

Answer (score 23):

The figure below shows a conic section (specifically an ellipse) with focus $F$ and directrix $D$. The conic is the intersection of the blue cone and the purple "cutting plane". The figure also shows the [Dandelin sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres) associated with $F$ and $D$. (Interestingly, the Wikipedia article mentions the focus-directrix property "can be proved" with Dandelin spheres, but doesn't give that proof!) Let's call the green "horizontal" plane containing the circle where the sphere meets the cone the *Dandelin plane*; call that circle the *Dandelin circle*.

Now, given $P$ on the conic, let $Q$ be the corresponding point on the Dandelin circle; that is, let $Q$ be the point where the segment joining $P$ to the cone apex meets the Dandelin plane. Let $R$ be the foot of the perpendicular dropped from $P$ to the Dandelin plane, and let $S$ be the foot of the perpendicular dropped from $P$ to the directrix.

[image: conic section]

([Original image credit](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~wws/cabripages/cone.html), with description of Dandelin spheres.)

Since segments $\overline{PF}$ and $\overline{PQ}$ are both tangent to the Dandelin sphere, we must have $|\overline{PF}|=|\overline{PQ}|$. (This, by the way, is the primary magic of the Dandelin sphere.)

We can massage the focus-directrix ratio for $P$ thusly:

> $$\frac{|\overline{PF}|}{|\overline{PS}|} = \frac{|\overline{PQ}|}{|\overline{PS}|}=\frac{|\overline{PR}|/(\sin\angle Q)}{|\overline{PS}|}=\frac{|\overline{PR}|}{|\overline{PS}|}\frac{1}{\sin\angle Q}=\frac{\sin \angle S}{\sin \angle Q} \tag{$\star$}$$

Clearly, $\angle S$ is constant as $P$ moves about the conic; it's the angle between the cutting plane and Dandelin plane. But $\angle Q$ is also constant: it's the ("exterior") angle that the surface (more precisely, a "generator" line) of the cone makes with the Dandelin plane. Therefore, the focus-directrix ratio is a constant.

To complete the answer to your question, all we have to do is prove that "(focal distance)-over-(major radius)" gives the same trigonometric ratio.

For now, we'll assume the conic is an ellipse (that is $\angle S$ is smaller than $\angle Q$).

Look at the figure "sideways", reducing all the elements to their intersections with the plane through the cone's axis, perpendicular to the directrix. I'll take $P$ to be the point on the conic closest to the directrix (which itself has projected into the point $S$), and $P^\prime$ the farthest point. ($Q$ and $Q^\prime$ are the corresponding points on the Dandelin plane, which has projected into a line.) Then $\overline{PP^\prime}$ is the major axis of the ellipse. The ellipse's focus, $F$, corresponds to the point where the incircle of $\triangle OPP^\prime$ meets $\overline{PP^\prime}$; the ellipse's center corresponds to $M$, the midpoint of $\overline{PP^\prime}$.

[image]

Now that we know where everything is, a couple more applications of the equal-tangent-segment property are all we need. With $a := |\overline{MP^\prime}|$ and $c := |\overline{MF}|$, we have

> $$\frac{\sin\angle S}{\sin\angle Q} = \frac{|\overline{PT}|}{|\overline{PP^\prime}|} = \frac{|\overline{QT}| - |\overline{QP}|}{2a} = \frac{(a+c)-(a-c)}{2a}= \frac{2c}{2a}= \frac{c}{a} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

For the hyperbola, overlapping elements muddle the diagram a bit, but the argument is essentially the same (with a simple sign change):

[image]

> $$\frac{\sin\angle S}{\sin\angle Q} = \frac{|\overline{PT}|}{|\overline{PP^\prime}|} = \frac{|\overline{QT}| + |\overline{QP}|}{2a} = \frac{(a+c)+(c-a)}{2a}= \frac{2c}{2a}= \frac{c}{a} \tag{$\star\star^\prime$}$$

There's no argument to make for the parabola, which has no "focal distance" or "major radius". However, one sees that, as the $\angle S$ nears $\angle Q$, the ratio of the lengths of these elements within an ellipse or hyperbola approaches $1$, as expected.

---

Thus, the "distance-to-focus-over-distance-to-directrix" ratio and the "focal-radius-over-major-radius" ratio (when defined) are the same constant that we happen to call the "eccentricity" of a conic. This discussion reveals the geometric meaning of that number. I suspect that most students these days had no idea that there *is* such meaning. Kudos to the teacher who assigned this problem as homework.

Comment: This explains how to solve for how PF/PD = e.  But it doesn't prove C/A = e.  I know you mentioned that now I simply have to prove that C/A = e is equal to the same trigonometric ratio.  But I need a proof that actually describes out the process of going from PF/PD = e to C/A = e
I realize I keep rewording myself but this isn't something I fully understand so I am trying to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: @Dona: I don't want to give everything away in case this is homework. To prove $c/a = \sin S/\sin Q$, look at the figure "sideways", projecting into a plane perpendicular to the directrix. The cutting plane projects to a line; the cone --between apex (say, $A$) and cutting plane-- projects to a triangle (say, $\triangle ABC$); the Dandelin sphere projects to the incircle of that triangle. The ellipse's major axis projects to the "purple" segment ($BC$), and its center to the midpoint (say, $M$) of the segment. Use good ol' 2-dimensional trig to massage the ratio $MF/MB$ into $\sin S/\sin Q$.

Comment: This was a homework assignment for my son last week, and since I couldn't help him then I figured I would try and understand it, and find out what the answer was. Even though it's past, I beleive that knowing the answer would maybe allow me to help him in the future (even though he is far beyond anything I ever learned). He already knew how to solve PF/PD=e but not how to get c/a=sinS/sinQ (I guess). Thank-you for continuing to help me.

Comment: Can you please tell me why PS is perpendicular on the intersection line of two planes ? @Blue

Comment: @sani: It's gratifying to know that this answer is still getting attention after 9(!) years. :) ... *"Can you please tell me why PS is perpendicular on the intersection line of two planes ?"* In the pink plane, we *choose* $S$ to be the foot of the perpendicular dropped from $P$; no problem there. In the green plane, the fact that $RS$ is *also* perpendicular to that line follows from $PR$ being perpendicular to the green plane, and from the so-called ["Three Perpendiculars Theorem" (math-only-math.com)](https://math-only-math.com/theorem-of-three-perpendiculars.html). ... Does this help?

Comment: Thanks to your answer I got to know this. 100 upvotes to your answer.

Comment: But I can not understand why we are dropping perpendicular from R on the directrix. Why it is necessary ? @Blue

Comment: Why we are choosing S to be the foot of the perpendicular from P on the directrix ? We could have chosen any other point on the directrix. We still get to the result because  the angle < S remains constant. But in that case the ratio PF / PS will be changed. That is supposed to remain constant.@Blue

Comment: @sani: "We could have chosen any other point on the directrix. We still get to the result because the angle < S remains constant." ... Ah, but the angle doesn't remain constant! ... Consider a perfectly cubical room w/floor $\square ABCD$ & ceiling $\square A'B'C'D'$. Clearly, $\angle ABC$ is $90^\circ$; but $\angle AB'C=60^\circ$, because $\triangle AB'C$ is equilateral. As a pt $P$ travels from $B$ to $B'$ (and beyond), $\angle APC$ gets smaller. Only when the plane of $\triangle APC$ is perpendicular to $BB'$ do we get the largest possible angle. That's how "dihedral" angles are defined.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling to understand this for 4 5 hours Thank you once again.

Comment: Hii @Blue Can you answer the following question of mine ? You seem to be very knowledgeable in this portion. That is why I am asking.                                                                 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061635/how-for-any-a-e-we-will-get-an-ellipse-on-the-double-cone-by-the-intersect