# Definition of Ecccentricity of an Ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

The definition of the eccentricity of a conic section given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)#Definitions) is $\dfrac {\sin \beta}{\sin\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are angles of incline from the horizontal of the slant of the cone and the cutting plane respectively.
(see diagram below from Wikipedia)

[image]

For an ellipse with semi-major and semi-minor axes $a,b$ the eccentricity is $e=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}a$. This can easily be proven using the focus-directrix definition.

> How can it be shown that the first definition is equivalent to the second, i.e. 
>   $$e=\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin\alpha}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}a$$

The challenge here is that the first and and second definitions are based on dimensions in different planes.

---

**Addendum (27 Jul 2017)**

Here's a [desmos implementation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n2eewtelju) of simulated orthographic projections of the conic section described above. The short blue line on the plane of the ellipse has length $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. From the diagram it can be seen that this is equal in length to the short black line, which has length $\dfrac {a\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}$. Equating and diving by $a$ gives the required result.

[image]

Comment: Hint: draw a triangle inside the ellipse and use the law of sines.

Comment: Not important, but the figure relates to an hyperbola.

Comment: A search on dandelin spheres and eccentricity gave [this answer by @Blue to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137374/eccentricity-of-an-ellipse/137462#137462).