# $\psi- \theta$ relation in Conics

Tags: differential-geometry, conic-sections

Angles $(\psi -\theta) $ relation is *unique* for Conics in a 3D situation.

// It is to seek $r- \psi$ of planar sections aka Conics on Gauss curvature $K=0$ cones for uniqueness and generality. *Motivation/Background* is mentioned although not absolutely necessary for the question at present. It needed mentioning due to the simplicity of their relationship in deeper contexts.

Angle $\psi $ is reckoned counterclockwise direction consistently from radius vector to one of parallel geodesics. Constant rotation $\phi$ and curvature in *two dimensions* shown here:

***Elliptic geometry***

$$ \phi_{Elliptic}= \psi  +\theta = const $$
Differentiating with respect to arc for elliptic straight lines
$$ \psi^{'}+\frac{d\theta}{ds} =  \psi^{'}+\frac{\sin \psi}{r} =\kappa_{gElliptic}=0$$
Re-integrate we get Clairaut's constant in polar coordinates:
$$ r\cdot \sin \psi = r_{min} = OE $$

***By Inversion***

the angle $\psi$ remains constant in magnitude but changes sense/relative direction into

***Hyperbolic geometry***

$$ \phi_{Hyperbolic}= (\pi-\psi ) +\theta = const $$
Differentiating with respect to arc for hyperbolic straight lines

$$ \psi^{'}-\frac{d\theta}{ds}  =\psi^{'}-\frac{\sin \psi}{r} =\kappa_{gHyperbolic} =0$$

Re-integrate we get  constant ;
$$ r/\sin \psi = r_{max} = OH $$

[image: Geods & Conics in 2D]

$ (r, \theta, z) $ are cylindrical coordinates and tangent at $P$ to conic makes angle $\psi $ to cone generator $OP$ to compare in this form their projections with elliptic and hyperbolic geodesics in two dimensions. //

If it is constant for example when $ \psi = \pi/2 \text{ at } G $ then we have a circle formed by cutting a cone of any semi-vertical angle with a plane perpendicular to the cone axis.

[image: psi -theta Relation]

How to establish/ find this relation?

Thanks for help in finding a reference or hints.

Comment: Angle $\theta$ in the figure is not the azimuthal angle of a cylindrical coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what kind of relation OP expects, but here's something ...

Let the generators of a cone (with vertex at the origin and $z$-axis as axis) make angle $\alpha$ with the $xy$-plane. Let a cutting plane parallel to the $y$-axis make angle $\beta$ with the $xy$-plane, and let it meet the cone at $V := (-v \cos\alpha,0,v \sin\alpha)$ (which will be a vertex of the conic). That is, the cone and plane have equations
$$z^2 \cos^2\alpha = (x^2+y^2)\sin^2\alpha \qquad\qquad (x+v\cos\alpha)\sin\beta=(z-v\sin\alpha)\cos\beta$$ 
We can parameterize the intersection of the plane and cone by
$$P := p (\cos\alpha \cos\theta, \cos\alpha\sin\theta,\sin\alpha)$$
with $\theta$-dependent $p$ determined by substituting $P$ into the plane equation. The fully-parametric form of $P$ is then
$$P = \frac{v \sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta \cos\theta}\,(\cos\alpha \cos\theta, \cos\alpha\sin\theta,\sin\alpha)$$ 
A tangent vector $P'$ is proportional to the derivative of $P$ with respect to $\theta$; in particular, we can take
$$P' = (
\sin\alpha\cos\beta\sin\theta, 
\cos\alpha\sin\beta-\sin\alpha\cos\beta\cos\theta, 
\sin\alpha \sin\beta \sin\theta)$$
Then, the angle $\psi$ between the generator $OP$ and tangent vector $P'$ satisfies
$$\cos\psi = \frac{P\cdot P'}{|P|\,|P'|}$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
P\phantom{^\prime}\cdot P' &= \frac{v \sin\beta \sin(\alpha+\beta) \sin\theta}{
\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta} \\[4pt]
|P\phantom{^\prime}|^2 = P\phantom{^\prime}\cdot P\phantom{^\prime} &= \frac{v^2 \sin^2(\alpha+\beta)}{(\sin\alpha\cos\beta
 - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta)^2} \\[4pt]
|P'|^2 = P'\cdot P' &= (\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta)^2 
+ \sin^2\beta \sin^2\theta
\end{align}$$
Thus,

> $$\begin{align}
> \cos\psi &= \phantom{\pm}\frac{\sin\beta \sin\theta}{\sqrt{(\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta)^2 
> + \sin^2\beta \sin^2\theta}} \\[4pt]
> \sin\psi &= \pm\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{(\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta)^2 
> + \sin^2\beta \sin^2\theta}} \\[4pt]
> \cot\psi &= \pm\frac{\sin\beta\sin\theta}{\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\theta} = \pm\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\alpha\cot\beta - \cos\alpha\cos\theta} \\[4pt]
> \end{align} $$

for appropriate choices of sign. $\square$

(I was hoping for something a little more elegant.)

---

Incidentally, [one can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137462/409) that, in general, the eccentricity of the conic is given by $e = \sin\beta/\sin\alpha$, but this observation doesn't seem to make the formulas appreciably better.

---

For the "standard" cone with $\alpha=\pi/4$, we have
$$\cot\psi = \pm\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\sin\theta}{\cot\beta-\cos\theta}$$

- For any cone cut by a horizontal plane, $\beta=0$ (giving a circle), we have $$\cot\psi = 0$$ so that $\psi$ is constantly $\pi/2$, which is geometrically obvious (as noted by OP).
- For the standard cone cut by a vertical plane, $\beta=\pi/2$ (giving a rectangular hyperbola), we have
  $$\cot\psi = \pm \sqrt{2}\tan\theta \quad\to\quad \cot\theta\cot\psi = \pm\sqrt{2}$$
  The reader can verify that this agrees with @Aretino's formula, with the condition $a=b$.
- For the standard cone cut by a comparably-inclined plane, $\beta=\alpha=\pi/4$ (giving a parabola), we have
  $$\cot\psi = \pm\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta} = \pm\sqrt{2}\,\cot\frac12\theta$$

Comment: I don't know why, but I interpreted the question as if it considered the plane to be perpendicular to the base of the cone. The general case of your formula is still fairly simple, in my opinion. Nice derivation.

Comment: Thanks, My question is for a  general Conic, not only hyperbola. (Inclination of base plane to cutting plane (in Blue's notation $ \beta) \ne \pi/2$.

Comment: $$ \pm \tan \psi = \cos \alpha \cdot\tan \theta + \cos \beta/ \epsilon \cdot \sec \theta $$ I have derived the  above relation with differential forms .. is substantially same as the one you have derived. But is it not  elegant enough ?

Comment: @Narasimham: (Your $\theta$ seems to be the complement of mine, but no matter.) Elegance-wise, it's okay. :)  I guess I hoped that one of the parameters would disappear or something. ... The reason I didn't bother write eccentricity $\epsilon$ into my equation the way you did into yours is that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ still remain; having *three* parameters that represent only *two* degrees of freedom doesn't seem very elegant. I briefly played with manipulating the relation into something with $\alpha$ (or $\beta$) and $\epsilon$ only, but didn't get anything *remotely* elegant.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: this solution refers only to the case when the plane is perpendicular to the base of the cone. See Blue's answer for the general case.

Let $G'$ be the projection of $G$ (vertex of the hyperbola) on the axis of the cone, $H$ the projection of $P$ on the axis of the hyperbola and $H'$ be the projection of $H$ on the axis of the cone. If we set:
$$
x=OH',\quad y=PH,\quad a=OG',\quad b=GG'=HH',
$$
it is easy to show that the usual equation holds:
$$
\tag{1}
{x^2\over a^2}-{y^2\over b^2}=1.
$$
If $T$ is the intersection of the tangent at $P$ with the axis $GH$ of the hyperbola, and $T'$ is the projection of $t$ on the axis of the cone, then we find
$$
OT'={a^2\over x}.
$$
The lengths of $PT$, $PO$ and $OT$ can be now found as a function of $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$, and $\psi=\angle OPT$ can be computed by the cosine rule as:
$$
\tag{2}
\cos\psi={\displaystyle\left(1+{b^2\over a^2}\right)x^2-b^2-a^2\over
\displaystyle x\sqrt{1+{b^2\over a^2}}
\sqrt{\left(1+{b^2\over a^2}\right)x^2
+{a^4\over x^2}-2a^2-b^2} }.
$$
If $\theta=\angle PH'H$ is the usual azimuthal angle, then 
$$
\tag{3}
\tan\theta={y\over b} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
x^2=\left(1+{y^2\over b^2}\right)a^2={a^2\over\cos^2\theta}. 
$$
Substituting that into $(2)$ finally gives:
$$
\cos\psi={\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\theta\over\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2}}.
$$

[image]

Comment: By substitution of  $ \,1+(b/a)^2 = \epsilon^2= ( \sin \beta/ \sin \alpha)^2$ evaluated  for $\cot \psi$ for  instance do you arrive at Blue's third relation?...  which should be independent of $ \epsilon $ by Blue's observation?

Comment: Some trick  :)  for generality ?

Comment: that could also be written as:

$$ \cot \psi = \frac {\epsilon \sin\theta}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-\cos^2\theta} } $$

Comment: @Narasimham Blue's relation can be written as $$\cot\psi=\pm{\sin\theta\over\epsilon\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cos\beta}.$$ For $\beta=\pi/2$ one recovers my relation above, which can be written as $$\cot\psi={\epsilon\over\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}}\tan\theta.$$

Comment: @Narasimham One could repeat the above reasoning for a general hyperbola and a general ellipse, but I don't see the point of doing that, as Blue's answer is simple and general.