Relation for eccentricity of conic and the angle subtended by a plane at a double cone.
Based of the half angle of a double cone, and the angle subtended by a plane with the cone's axis, is it possible to determine the eccentricity of the conic section which is formed by this.
I think it should be
$$\tan{π((π/2)-b)\over 2a},$$
where
$b=\ $angle subtended by plane with axis of cone
and
$a=\ $half angle of the cone.

See this ancient answer of mine.

In the case of an ellipse, you can find all the relevant formulae in this old answer of mine (with an appendix here).
We can in particular compute the ratio $\eta={\text{minor axis}\over\text{major axis}}$, which translated into your notations becomes:
$$
\eta^2={\sin(b-a)\sin(b+a)\over\cos^2 a}.
$$
The square of the eccentricity can then be found as $e^2=1-\eta^2$, that is
$$
e^2=1-{\sin(b-a)\sin(b+a)\over\cos^2 a}={\cos^2b\over\cos^2a},
$$
where I used some standard trig equalities in the last passage.
Hence we have the nice result:
$$
e={\cos b\over\cos a}.
$$
As it often happens, this formula gives the correct result even in the case of a hyperbola or parabola.

But isn't cos b/ cos a bounded, whereas e is not

$\cos a$ can approach zero, if you want a large eccentricity.

But isn't 'a' a constant. The half angle of the cone can't vary

The relation should be in terms of the tangent, if I am not wrong

I'd suggest you to test this result with GeoGebra.

Could you please tell me how to do so. I have been looking for it for a long time now. I wanted a graph which relates the eccentricity of the conic formed and the angle of the plane. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you

You can find the same result in this beautiful answer, which uses Dandelin's spheres: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137462/255730 Note that $\angle S$ and $\angle Q$ are the complementary of your angles $b$ and $a$.

Thanks a lot. The same person who wrote that answer also commented on mine above.

@SidN: For a given cone, eccentricity is bounded.

@Blue Wow, I didn't know that. I thought eccentricity was unbounded for all cones. Makes sense now. Your answer was great as well. Thanks for the help
